# javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException Error SSL but works in Postman

Tags: android, web-services, laravel, ssl, retrofit

I have a service, which I connect my android application without problems, I work on my development server.
But when the service is in production server, this error occurs as the image below.

[image]
 - On both servers I test the postman and works.

[image]
In the part of served I use Laravel

And

In the Android use

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.4.0'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.0.0'



@GET("/api/account/{accountId}/balance")
public void getBalanceAccount(
        @Path("accountId") int accountId,
        CancelableCallback<Balance> balanceCancelableCallback
);



public Gson providesGson() {

    return new GsonBuilder()
            .registerTypeAdapter(Date.class, new DateTypeAdapter())
            .create();

}

private OkHttpClient myOkHttpClient(){

    OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();
    okHttpClient.setReadTimeout(70 * 1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    okHttpClient.setConnectTimeout(70 * 1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

    return okHttpClient;
}

public RestAdapter providesRestAdapter(Gson gson) {

    return new RestAdapter.Builder()
            .setClient(new OkClient(myOkHttpClient()))
            .setLog(new AndroidLog("Retrofit"))
            .setLogLevel(BuildConfig.DEBUG ? RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL : RestAdapter.LogLevel.NONE)
            .setEndpoint(BuildConfig.BASE_URL_STYLE)
            .setConverter(new GsonConverter(gson))
            .setRequestInterceptor(new SessionRequestInterceptorGetTokenAPI())
            .build();

}
```

A long time I am trying to solve.
But without success, any opinion can help.

thank you

## Resolved

uruullll

```
private OkHttpClient myOkHttpClient(){

    try{
        OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();
        okHttpClient.setReadTimeout(70 * 1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        okHttpClient.setConnectTimeout(70 * 1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

        final TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[] { new X509TrustManager() {
            @Override
            public void checkClientTrusted(
                    java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] chain,
                    String authType) throws CertificateException {
            }

            @Override
            public void checkServerTrusted(
                    java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] chain,
                    String authType) throws CertificateException {
            }

            @Override
            public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                return null;
            }
        } };


        final SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
        sslContext.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());
        // Create an ssl socket factory with our all-trusting manager
        final SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = sslContext.getSocketFactory();

        okHttpClient.setSslSocketFactory(sslSocketFactory);

        return okHttpClient;

    }catch (Exception e){
        return null;
    }
}
```

tks

Comment: Read through this http://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl.html#CommonProblems

Comment: It is possible to operate without the keys? @Roberto Artiles Astelarra

Comment: resolved @Roberto Artiles Astelarra

Comment: @FilipNovid It's VERY BAD IDEA to trust all certificates, you should never do that in production. I guess your API has self-signed ssl certificate, in that case you should ship that certificate with your android app so that it can validate it itself. If you dont want to, you can check serv certificate using hardcoded domain name.